# Lua - how to make an if condition with an string with a variable %d in the middle?

Tags: string, lua, character

So I am trying to compare if a string match an pattern ( and I must know that after the string there is nothing else !!! ) and inside that string is a number ( I don't know which number is )

I made this function but it don't work in some cases and I think there must already be a solution!

```
function Match(string, pattern)
    local start , final = string.find(string,pattern)
    local len = string.len( string )
    if len == final then return true else return false end
end
```

and I call it like this

```
    if Match(item_loop_name,"!MEx CH %d+ %- "..name) == true then 
        --bla bla bla doing something
    end
```

the problem my variable name sometimes have special characters like - ! % that mess with string.find

Thanks a lot

Comment: if you don't provide some example we cannot help you too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure your pattern is found at the end of the string you can simply anchor your pattern at the end of the string using `$`

`local str = "I own 3 pigs and a cow"`

`"I own %d+ pigs"` would match.

`"I own %d+ pigs$"` would not.

So instead of checking the string's last character's position vs the string length you can simply do something like

```
local stringOk = yourString:match("yourPattern$") and true or false
```

or

```
local stringOk = yourString:find("yourPattern$") and true or false
```

Please refer to the Lua manual!

Please understand that no further help can be given without string examples.